# How to programmatically clear the filesystem memory cache in C++ on a Linux system?

Tags: c++, c, linux, caching

I'm writing a benchmark tool in C++ where I want to clear the filesystem memory cache between experiments. I'm aware of the following console commands:

```
sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

My question is how can i do this programmatically directly within C++?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just write to it :

```
sync();

std::ofstream ofs("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches");
ofs << "3" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 15):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
int fd;
char* data = "3";

sync();
fd = open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, data, sizeof(char));
close(fd);
```

Comment: This is a better answer because it includes a sync. Which is important because drop_caches is a *debugging* tool and it does not always get the data on disk before dropping it.

Comment: A better answer that what?  Both of the answers I see include a `sync`.

Comment: If that's true then this is a bit dangerous - what happens if a process writes a file in the background?  Is the data written between sync() and open() just lost?

Comment: @ZanLynx: drop_caches is non-destructive and will only free clean caches (ones that have not been synced to disk).  Thus calling sync() before doesn't make the operation any more safe, but rather increases the number of caches that can be dropped.  See: /usr/src/linux/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Comment: @kalaxy: When I used to run -mm kernels in 2008 it was *definitely* not safe.

Comment: If drop_caches is unsafe, your kernel is bugged. No modern kernel will have a problem with this.

Comment: You don't need `char *data="3";`.  You can just use `write(fd, "3", 1);`.  (`sizeof(char)` is required to be 1, but it's up to you whether writing `1` or `sizeof(char)` is clearer in that context.  If you were going to do anything, maybe do `strlen("3")` or put the string in a `const char data[]` and take the sizeof that.)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better way is to sync just the file systems which contains your descriptors using `syncfs()`. Or even better, simply use `fsync()`.

```
int fd = open(...);   // Open your files
write(...);           // Your write calls
fsync(fd);            // Sync your file
close(fd);            // Close them
```

`fsync()` can fail if your descriptor is invalid. Look for `errno` if it returns `-1`.