# Programmatically drop Linux cache as non-root user

Tags: c++, linux, permissions, embedded-linux, procfs

For testing purposes, I can drop cached memory by writing to the drop_caches file in Linux under the procfs. I can only do this as root. This is on embedded Linux so there is no sudo.

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I can write to the file programmatically in c++ by doing something from the post --> [How to programmatically clear the filesystem memory cache in C++ on a Linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818606/how-to-programmatically-clear-the-filesystem-memory-cache-in-c-on-a-linux-syst/6818653#6818653)

```
sync();
std::ofstream ofs("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches");
ofs << "3" << std::endl;
```

The challenge is wanting to do this while running the app as a non-root user. On reboot, the permissions look like:

```
# cd /proc/sys/vm/
# ls -lrt drop_caches 
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Feb 13 19:50 drop_caches
```

And you cannot seem to change those permissions - even as root:

```
# chmod 777 drop_caches 
chmod: drop_caches: Operation not permitted
# chown user:user drop_caches 
chown: drop_caches: Operation not permitted
```

How can I accomplish this on Linux? Is it possible to change permissions of a procfs file? I can fully customize my kernel if necessary. Thanks -

Comment: Edit the /etc/sudoers file to allow users to run those commands?

Comment: there is no sudo since this is embedded linux - I've edited the post to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an auxiliary executable (be very careful, it is dangerous) which any user can run it with root permissions.

This is called [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

For safety reasons, you cannot `setuid` a shell script.

Extracting from the wiki how to use it:

> The setuid and setgid bits are normally set with the command chmod by
>   setting the high-order octal digit to 4 (for setuid) or 2 (for
>   setgid). "chmod 6711 file" will set both the setuid and setgid bits
>   (2+4=6)

### Update

As @rici noted, you still will need to have execution permission to execute this process, so you can remove execution permission from `others` and keep it only on `group`. So, only who is member of the group can execute it.

Comment: You can also create an auxiliary executable which only a certain user (or group) can run with root permissions, which is just a bit less dangerous.

Comment: This is technically correct.  But I think the "it is dangerous" note is terribly underemphasized.  Implementing this utility "perfectly" -- a perfectly secure setuid root binary that did nothing but purge the VM cache without side effect -- **is, straight up, a denial of service attack waiting to happen** for many (probably most) workloads out there.  If you must have a setuid helper, this is how you do it.  But don't do this.  Find a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: @AndyRoss I dont think there is a better way to solve the problem