# How to clear drive cache in C when reading files on NTFS

Tags: c, linux, caching, benchmarking, ntfs

I am making a drive benchmark in C on Linux operating system, and I have encountered a problem on NTFS file system. Heres some code that writes many new files:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
{
    fd = open(nextfile, O_WRONLY | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC | O_CREAT );
    write(fd, buff, size);
    fsync(fd);
    close(fd);
}
```

and that works fine, but when I want to read all created files, the fsync function seems not work. Heres some code that reads all files:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
{
    fd = open(nextfile, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC);
    read(fd, buff, size);
    fsync(fd);
    close(fd);
}
```

When testing my old pendrive I get the time 4MB/s on write, and 267MB/s on read which is obviously not true, but when testing ext4 file system the read time is correct. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that you want a C++ answer? Given that your code is C, and that the best answer probably involves using OS specific api...

Comment: is it a single program, first u r writing files and then reading? or two diff program? Between this is wild guess,  if u are creating-writing and then reading those same files in your single program what I can say, u should try fsync on parent directory in which those files reside as well.

Comment: Yes this is one single program, first I write, then I read. I try fsync on directory as you said

Comment: What `fsync` after a `read` is supposed to do for you? Why do you call `fsync` even if you have opened the file with `O_SYNC` flag?

Comment: As my thinking do not find any type of bug in your code, Can you please try by calling close(fd) first and then fsync.

Comment: @DavideBerra so fsync has nothing to do with read function? You asked why I use O_SYNC with fsync... I have no idea, but it works when I am writing to NTFS file system. I just wanted this to work on both NTFS and ext4 file systems. In ext4 I don't need to use fsync functions.

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil you can not use fsync after close. I tried and fsync has generated "Invalid argument"

Comment: When I try to read first file after writing all files, I don't need to wait any time, it is almost instantly, so the data already must be somewhere in the memory or cache right? How i can flush them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically clear the filesystem memory cache in C++ on a Linux system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818606/how-to-programmatically-clear-the-filesystem-memory-cache-in-c-on-a-linux-syst)

Comment: See also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861880/programmatically-drop-linux-cache-as-non-root-user

Comment: It works! Thank you :)
Should I now edit my question and add the answer or self answer?

Comment: I think you should self-answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by adding following code below after the write loop.

```
int fd;
char* data = "3";

sync();
fd = open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, data, sizeof(char));
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unmounting the filesystem before doing the read tests is a common way of ensuring that nothing is cached.  The fsync() in your read routine is mostly pointless (but may cause file access timestamps to be flushed depending on mount options).   I assume the provided code is only a sketch, but I hope your actual code is testing the return values from open and read.

Comment: Of course the real code checks return values of read, write, open, etc. functions. I have omitted all this checks to simplify the code. Thank you for you answer.