# Programmatically clear cache on mounted (SSD) disk in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, caching, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

I'm writing an application where disk performance is interesting. I previously used an older, mechanical disk and used the technique in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818606/how-to-programmatically-clear-the-filesystem-memory-cache-in-c-on-a-linux-syst) to clear the cache before measuring performance:

```
// Clear cache for benchmarking                                               
sync();    
std::ofstream ofs("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches");
ofs << "3" << std::endl;
ofs.close();
```

That worked well and gave me expected results - a measured disk sequential read speed of ~100 MB/s when clearing the cache, many times higher when cache was left alone.

The other day I installed an SSD disk, mounted under /media/. After a fresh computer restart, the first couple of measurements are as expected (around 300 MB/s) but when the cache kicks in they are obviously much higher.

My problem now is that the lines of code I previously used have no effect since moving the application to the SSD. Does that cache behave in a different way, maybe? Anything I need to do differently to clear it? The only thing that works now is a computer restart.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this: Please leave a comment and point out why so that I can fix it.

Comment: That's weird, those disks should behave identically, as the cache is in a higher layer of the OS... could it be something else, like read cache ON the SSD (note: I'm not even sure they have one...)?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Could you elaborate on the read cache idea? I am a newbie on most of these things.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/309613/do-solid-state-disks-ssds-have-a-buffer-cache ... it should only matter if you don't read much. If you read 100s of megabytes, the first couple of mbs of stored content shouldn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say just what you were doing and whether anything else was somehow working with that data too. You can only evict unused data from the cache with `drop_caches` - if for some reason the data is required to be kept (e.g. because it's dirty and needs to be written back) it won't be evictable. From the [kernel documentation for drop_caches](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> This is a non-destructive operation and will not free any dirty objects.
>   To increase the number of objects freed by this operation, the user may run
>   `sync` prior to writing to `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.  This will minimize the
>   number of dirty objects on the system and create more candidates to be
>   dropped.