# ‘sync’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, caching

I want to clear cache during an ongoing script before I benchmark some results, and I use the answer mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818606/how-to-programmatically-clear-the-filesystem-memory-cache-in-c-on-a-linux-syst) question for that.

The answer basically is:

```
sync();

std::ofstream ofs("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches");
ofs << "3" << std::endl;
```

But when I do that, I get:

```
rTree.cpp:157:4: error: ‘sync’ was not declared in this scope
  157 |    sync();
      |    ^~~~
```

I tried to google, but almost every link is related to variables/methods not being declared in the scope (I can see why, but that doesn't really solve my problem). Any would be great, thanks...

Comment: what is `sync` ? Don't blindy copy others code without knowing what it is (not even fro SO ;). Did you include the necessary header?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yup, `<istream>`

Comment: I somewhat suspect it's the POSIX call to sync memory buffers to on-disk commit. [see here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sync). You included `unistd.h`, *right* ?

Comment: if it was from `istream` it would be `std::sync`, but it isnt

Comment: @WhozCraig it works (compiles)! It should work on runtime too. Thanks :)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I didn't know (at all) it's from that header. So...

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah yes, I did that after the link was posted :)